# Editing an array from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

`data.js`

```
var idToExport = ["123", "456"]
module.exports = idToExport;
```

`app.js`

```
var data = require("./data.js")
data.push("789");

console.log(data[2]) // prints out 789
```

However, when I check data.js again, the pushed value is not there, it is just back to `["123", "456"]` why is this?

Comment: after push, where are you writing the array in to file ?

Comment: Are you trying to actually update the hardcoded array in data.js? i.e. do you expect to see a different array in data.js after running app.js?

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that inserts and updates an array in another file @hugomarisco

Comment: @li x You don't have to add the tag name in the question, this is the exclusive purpose of tags. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: @RenatoGama I think we submitted edit's very close together as when I edited your title change was already in effect..

Comment: Thats fine, @li x ... concurrency problems haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `data.js` as `data.json` with just the array in it :

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

To access the data in your `app.js`, you can require it (which will create a singleton)

```
var data = require('data.json');
console.log(data) // [1,2,3,4]
```

Or read the file via `fs.readFile`.

And if you want to modify the array in `data.json`, you will need to use the `fs` node module : you can see the doc here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback